# How to avoid writing repeated code in catch blocks?

Tags: c++, optimization, exception, try-catch, throw

I am using QT 4.8 (C++) for desktop application project, and writing exception handling which is as follows :

```
void callerMethod()
{
  try
  {
   method1();
  }
  catch(Exception1& e)
  {
    // display critcal error message
    // abort application
  }
  catch(std::Exception& e)
  {
   // print exception error message
  }
  catch(...)
  {
   // print unknown exception message
  } 
}

void method1()
{
  try
  {
   // some initializations
   // some operations (here exceptions can occur)
   // clean-up code (for successful operation i.e no exception occurred)
  }
  catch(Exception1& e)
  {
   // clean-up code
   throw e;
  }
  catch(Exception2& e)
  {
   // clean-up code
   throw e;
  }
  catch(Exception3& e)
  {
   // clean-up code
   throw e;
  }
  catch(...)
  {
   // clean-up code
   throw;
  }
}
```

So my question do I need to write the **clean-up code in every catch block**?
Is there any way I can **avoid writing repeated code**?

**NOTE**:: [ **In method1()** ] I want to re-throw exceptions which occurred 
           to my caller.So I can not catch them in single catch block, 
           because then type information will be lost.

Comment: Try to reduce the amount of clean-up code needed by using smart pointers, container classes etc. Ideally there should be no clean-up code at all.

Comment: It appears that what you want to do is simply `try { /* may throw */ } catch(specific_exception const& e) { /* terminate */ }`. If you don't care for exception types `Exception1`, `Exception2` and so on, then *don't* catch them.

Comment: Also, even if you do catch by reference, you *should* rethrow using `throw;` instead of `throw e;` to prevent slicing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Method1 can be much simplified by two concepts:

1. [RAII](http://www.hackcraft.net/raii/). Put *any* clean-up code into destructors, and the clean-up code will be centralized.
2. Use the unqualified `throw`, and you won't need to know about the type of exception thrown.

So, `method1()` should look like:

```
void method1()
{
     // some initializations of RAII objects
     // some operations (here exceptions can occur)
}
```

The first `catch` clause in `callerMethod` can be removed if you derive Exception1 from `std::exception`, since the `what()` method is virtual.

Comment: But I want to handle Exception1 separately in callerMethod().
If Exception1 occurred I want to abort the application.

Comment: @AnwarShaikh: You can still do that. RAII solves your cleanup problem only.

Comment: Ok. got it!!
Single catch(std::exception& e) and using what() I think i can get the exception type.
And I am unaware about RAII, It seems it will solve my problem of clean-up. I will investigate about it. 
Any good resource link for RAII will help. 

Thank you.. Thiton and Nawaz.

Comment: @AnwarShaikh: Have linked to an appropriate tutorial.

Comment: @AnwarShaikh: You can read RAII idiom [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) which has explained it in short. And [this paper](http://www.two-sdg.demon.co.uk/curbralan/papers/europlop/ExecutingAroundSequences.pdf) has long explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You should throw exceptions as low as possible and catch them as high as possible in the call chain. This automatically leads to less code duplication, and centralizes error handling. You are throwing/catching all in one place, which seems a bit ... forced.

I often do this kind of thing (especially for program-ending exceptions:

```
int main()
try
{
    function_calls_that_may_throw();
    // ...
}
catch(my_exception& e)
{
    e.do_exception_stuff();
}
catch(std::exception& e)
{
    std::cout << e.what();
}
catch(...)
{
    std::cout << "Something bad happened.\n";
}
```

This is only possible for throwing exceptions you don't plan on handling better or retrying the failed operation or something.

The pro of this approach is that all/most error handling code is at the top-level of your program, and all the functions in the call chain don't have to worry one bit about this stuff, all they do is throw an exception when they feel like it.

Answer (score 0):

If all your clean up code is totally identical, you can do everything in your catch (...) block:

```
try {
   // code
} catch (...) {
   // cleanup
   throw;
}
```

If your code varies slightly, you can always call a cleanup function:

```
try {
   // code
} catch (exc1 ex) {
   cleanup(args);
   // exc1 specific
   throw;
} catch (exc2 ex) {
   cleanup(args);
   // exc2 specific
   throw;
} catch (...) {
   cleanup(args);
   throw;
}
```

Comment: If I write single catch(..) which throw exception then, In caller method How will I know that which exception was occurred.  
Because I want to handle Exception1 which abort the application.